# Can't use UIColor(red:,green:,blue:,) in FontColor of SKLabelNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I don't know why I can't use that in `SpriteKit`. If I try `UIColor(red:156,green:187,blue:214)` the color turns out white. It is not the color that it should be and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Change

`UIColor(red:156,green:187,blue:214)`

to:

`UIColor(red: 156/255.0, green: 187/255.0, blue: 214/255.0)`

Comment: I tried so hard to find answer but i cant find any answer , coz no one will ask this lol